# How to convert a OPENLAYERS 3 postcompose method to a normal one?

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to animate a line based on the given coordinates array comprising of latitude and longitude and I want to call my function just once and my coordinates name is: replayData.

```
map.on('postcompose', function (event) {
    var vectorContext = event.vectorContext;
    var frameState = event.frameState;
    vectorContext.setFillStrokeStyle(null, animatedLineStroke);
    var features = lineVectorSource.getFeatures();
    for (var k = 0; k < features.length; k++) {
        var feature = features[k];
        if (!feature.get('finished')) {
            var coords = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
            var elapsedTime = frameState.time - feature.get('start');
            var elapsedPoints = elapsedTime * pointsPerMs;
            if (elapsedPoints >= coords.length) {
                feature.set('finished', true);
            }
            var maxIndex = Math.min(elapsedPoints, coords.length);
            var currentLine = new ol.geom.LineString(coords.slice(0, maxIndex));
            if (feature.get('iValue') == undefined || feature.get('iValue') < k) {
                // drawMovingCarMarker(coords, k);
                feature.set('iValue', k)
            }
            vectorContext.drawLineStringGeometry(currentLine, feature);
        }
    }
    frameState.animate = true;
});
```

What this function is doing is first collecting all the values from for loop and then starting the animation. And because of this if I've 5 points the line between first two points will be drawn 5 times then 4,3, and so on.
Any help would be entertained. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I have problems understanding the issue. Could you please demonstrate the problem in a JSFiddle (for example based on this [one](http://jsfiddle.net/q281ry67/))?